# Volume profile chart in lightning chart

Tags: lightningchart

is there way to show bar char horizontally on same axis where there is line series ?

Or is there any option to share axis of linechart and barchart ?

it looks like its xychart and this is different

```
const barChart = lc
    .BarChart({
        type: BarChartTypes.Horizontal,
        theme: Themes.cyberSpace,
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not inside `BarChart` since its a chart type of its own.

However, you can show bars, histograms, volumes, etc. easily within XY charts as well. For example, using step series, segment series or rectangles.
https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/features/xy/histogram/